# Laravel 4.2 to 5.0 - app.blade.php loads before my layouts

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view

I am upgrading from Laravel 4.2 to 5.0. 
When I get to the home page, '/' the app.blade.php file loads and not the one specified in my HomeController which is home.blade.php. I don't understand why app.blade.php loads first, I see nowhere a command asking to start form it.

Also the @yield @section etc... that are supposed to call in other views don't load either.

Am I missing something? I followed the instructions on the Laravel site for the upgrade but this was not mentioned anywhere.

Thanks for your help!

Edit Code:

The route:

```
Route::get('/', array(
        'as'    => 'home',
        'uses'  => 'HomeController@home'
));
```

The RouteServiceProvider:

```
 <?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Router;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * This namespace is applied to the controller routes in your routes file.
     *
     * In addition, it is set as the URL generator's root namespace.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $namespace = null;

    /**
     * Define your route model bindings, pattern filters, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Router $router)
    {
        parent::boot($router);

    }

    /**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Router  $router
     * @return void
     */
    public function map(Router $router)
    {
        $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function($router)
        {
            require app_path('Http/routes.php');
        });
    }
    }
```

The HomeController:

```
<?php

class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function home() {
        return View::make('home');

    }}
```

Comment: We need more information, can you share your `routes.php` file with us? And maybe (part of the) the contents of the `RouteServiceProvider.php` is also useful.

Comment: Can you show your routes.php file?

Comment: @JeroenNoten Sure, I added it to the question.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe the route cache has to be cleared..? `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: I tried doesn't work :-(  I don't understand where something overrides my routing. The other routes work but now i need to replace all the {{ HTML::style  because they are escaped...

Comment: The Illuminate ViewServiceProvider is causing the view 'app' to load before. I change it to 'home' and then it works. Is there no way to set that up differently?